# Out of Stack Space VBA for Large data set

Tags: database, vba, excel

I'm trying to create a new sheet for each set of rows with the same value in a column. My column 'line_name' has entries like Line 1, Line 2, Line 3..., Line 12

I would like to create a new sheet for all rows with line_name = Line 1, create a new sheet for all rows with line_name = Line 2... etc.

I keep getting an Out of Stack Space Error. Is it a problem with my code or is my sheet (40K rows) too big?

**Sub Copy_To_Worksheets**

```
Sub Copy_To_Worksheets()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
Dim My_Range As Range
Dim FieldNum As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim CCount As Long
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim ErrNum As Long

'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
Set My_Range = Range("A1:S" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
My_Range.Parent.Select

If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
   My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
           vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
    Exit Sub
End If

'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
FieldNum = 1

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

With ws2
    'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
    My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
    Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

        'Filter the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
         Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

        'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
        CCount = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                 .Areas(1).Cells.Count
        On Error GoTo 0
        If CCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                 & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                 & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                   vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
        Else
            'Add a new worksheet
            Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            On Error Resume Next
            WSNew.Name = cell.Value
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                WSNew.Name = "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000")
                Err.Clear
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            'Copy the visible data to the new worksheet
            My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            With WSNew.Range("A1")
                ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Select
            End With
        End If

        'Show all data in the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

    Next cell

    'Delete the ws2 sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

End With

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

If ErrNum > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
         & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
         & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
End If

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
My_Range.Parent.Select
ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
End Sub
```

**Function LastRow**

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
    Sheets("Profitability and Productivity").Select
    Application.Run _
    "file_name.xlsx!Copy_To_Worksheets"
    Cells.Select
    Application.Run _
        "file_name.xlsx!Copy_To_Worksheets"
    Range("P20").Select
End Function
```

Comment: Both your Sub and Function are calling each other! Fix your `Function LastRow` will appropriate goal. It should return a Long.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your code is recursive:

```
Sub Copy_To_Worksheets()
    ...
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:S" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    ...
End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    ...
    Application.Run "file_name.xlsx!Copy_To_Worksheets"
    ...
End Function
```

So it will very quickly run out of memory.

It seems very strange for a "LastRow" function to invoke a call to a macro to move data to another worksheet, so I don't think you really intended to have that "Application.Run" (actually, there are two of them) in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you were trying to separate out the code into 2 parts and got confused.

This is what your LastRow() should do:

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    Dim oRng as Range
    Set oRng = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If oRng Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "NO BOTTOM FREE CELL FOUND!"
        LastRow = 0
    Else
        LastRow = oRng.Row
    End If
End Function
```